# Should I feel bad about not giving a bounty to an answer on a bountied question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I asked this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153340/why-is-skype-startup-sound-scratchy-grainy) a while ago and gave a bounty of 50 rep to it. I received some good answers in no time and went through them.  Although they didn't fix my problem.

Next the bounty was over and I was left with the "Grace Period".  So I went through the answers again and tried the solutions.  None of them worked. Still.

Then I allowed myself to concentrate on that problem for 3 hours and eventually I found a solution.

At last I was left with a question that is already solved and had 2 answers waiting for me to choose the best one.  Really, I can't choose any one of them for the bounty, so I upvoted both of them and left an answer.

For the next couple of hours on Askubuntu I have a guilty feeling for not giving out the bounty.  I don't know why, but I just felt bad for what I'd just done.

So should I feel bad about that?  A good answer will be appreciated, since this is my first bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should feel very bad and guilty. *just kidding*

No, don't. They tried to answer it, and you happened to come up with an answer. Simple as that. Do note that you can't award a bounty to yourself, so that rep is lost - forever gone.

Comment: Oh, it automatically awarded half that rep to an answer(as I read on the Faq) 5 minutes ago.

Comment: So should I completely ignore that?